# Prove that f is a homomorphism and f(Sn) is a subgroup of An+2

Tags: group-theory

Let $n≥3$. For $a$ in $S_n$ and $b$ in Sn+2 such that $a(k) = a'(k)$ for $k = 1,...,n$, $a'(n+1) = n+1$, $a'(n+2) = n+2$. If $f$: $Sn$ -> Sn+2 such that $f(a) = a'$ for $a$ in $A_n$ and $f(a) = a'$(n+1 n+2) otherwise.

i) Question: How do I show that f is a homomorphism? Attempt: I've already covered every case except when $a$ is not in $A_n$ and $b$ is in $A_n$. In which case $f(ab) = (ab)'$(n+1 n+2) = $a'b'$(n+1 n+2) but this does not become $a'$(n+1 n+2)$b'$ = $f(a)f(b)$ since $A_n$ is not abelian. It only worked for when $a$ is in $A_n$ and $b$ is not.

ii) Question: How do I show that $f(S_n)$ is a subgroup of An+2? Attempt: I've already done the subgroup test, how do I show that it is a subset?

Comment: Ok, done editing.

Comment: No, a,b are in Sn. f(b) = b' is in Sn+2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i) remark that in $f(ab)=a'b'(n+1,n+2)$, the support of $b'$ is included in $\{1,...,n\}$ whereas the support of $(n+1,n+2)$ is in $\{n+1,n+2\}$ so that $b'$ and $(n+1,n+2)$ commute (since they are permutations with disjoint supports), hence you do find

$$f(ab)=a'(n+1,n+2)b'=f(a)f(b)$$

Remark that you have to apply the same trick when both $a'$ and $b'$ are not in $A_n$.

ii)  Write $a$ as a product of transpositions $a=\tau_1...\tau_{r}$. Now :

$$f(a)=f(\tau_1)...f(\tau_{r})=[\tau_1(n+1,n+2)][\tau_2(n+1,n+2)]...[\tau_{r}(n+1,n+2)] $$

Now use the same trick as before to show :

$$f(a)=\tau_1...\tau_{r}(n+1,n+2)^{r}$$

Now the signature of such an element is :

$$\epsilon(f(a))=(-1)^r(-1)^r=1$$